# Add Angular Function in the View to pass ng-repeat value to controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

What is the correct way to add an Angular function in the view?  Example:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in items" (how to fire function and pass i) allItems(i)">
```

I have done `<div ng-repeat="i in items" ng-if="allItems(i)">`, but this seems incorrect to me.

Would it be `<div ng-repeat="i in items" ng-init="allItems(i)">`

Comment: I don't understand what you wanted to do?

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) . Explain what you are trying to accomplish...the method shown is all wrong whatever it is you are doing. Broken code isn't a good substitute for a proper explanation

Comment: @PankajParkar I want to trigger the function each time the ng-repeat creates the div.  So in the controller I have 'scope.allItems = function(i){...}'

Comment: @RooksStrife why don't you  loop the collection inside controller and call `allItems` method from there, rather than making it to dependant on UI rendering. like `angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item){ $scope.allItems(item); })`

Comment: @charlietfl The problem = how to CORRECTLY fire an angular function to pass the value of an ng-repeat to the controller.

Comment: no...that is your conclusion to solve the problem ... that isn't what you are trying to accomplish by calling that function. As @PankajParkar already mentioned this all belongs in controller or a custom filter

Comment: using `ng-if` is a very expensive way to filter array ..especially if you use a function to do it

Comment: @charlietfl  I think this is going off the rails a bit... Yes I know I can do a .forEach and there are plenty other way to go about this.  All I was curious about is when you do tie the function to the view with Angular (without using a ng-click) - is there a best practice to fire it?

Comment: you don't control firing it...each instance will get fired many times during digest cycle

Comment: As for best practices... not putting it in the view at all is at top of the list. But you still aren't giving anyone enough detail to help you get rid of it

Comment: @charlietfl Maybe the best way to put this is how to pass i to the controller for use and I think what I am getting is to just handle the loop in the controller.

Comment: start back at the very first comment...what does this function do? And why aren't you doing this in the controller...BEFORE passing data to view. You are really stuck on your view function ... but it shouldn't even be in the view and we don't know what it is you are using it for

Comment: Read the XY problem link I posted in second comment